# Selecting part of circle

Tags: image, titanium, appcelerator

Before, there is image:

[image: a busy cat]

I am totally new in Titanim(Appcelerator). There is task: I must draw or import and select the definite regions of circle. When clicked, it must change colour. Your help will be appreciated.

With regards

Answer (score 0):

Plz Keep two images one with new background and one with original background.Just change the image path and you would be good to go.Something like this

```
Ti.UI.backgroundColor = 'white';
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();
var image = Ti.UI.createImageView({
  image:'/images/myimage.png'
});
image.addEventListener('click',function(e){
image.image="images/newimage";
});
win.add(image);
win.open();
```

Comment: I have a question. The middle segment also must be clicked.